# tableView images randomly disappearing

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am modifying my paid for app to a free with IAP.

Some group types are free and some will need to be paid for.

On the tableView controller, there is a padlock UIImageView that displays each "locked" item if it is a part of a locked group.

When someone buys that group, or all, that padlock is meant to disappear.  This padlock is not a part of the code that prevents the user from seeing the details as I have that code somewhere else and it works fine.

Initially, "Padlock" displays accurately.  However, If I scroll up and down on the tableView, the padlocks will randomly disappear.

How to prevent this?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    //
    //  We need to fetch our reusable cell.
    //
    let cell: UITableViewCell       = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Resource.SpeciesCell)!


    //
    //  Get all of the components of the cell.
    //
    let specieImage: UIImageView    = cell.viewWithTag(Resource.SpeciesImageTag) as! UIImageView
    let specieName: UILabel         = cell.viewWithTag(Resource.SpeciesNameTag) as! UILabel
    let specieGenus: UILabel        = cell.viewWithTag(Resource.SpeciesGenusTag) as! UILabel
    let specieFamily: UILabel       = cell.viewWithTag(Resource.SpeciesFamilyTag) as! UILabel

    //  Set our name, family and genus labels from our data.
    //
    specieName.text     = self.species[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].specie

    specieFamily.text   = ""

    specieGenus.text    = self.species[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].speciesSubgroup




    // **** Adding Padlock Begins HERE  ****

    let padLock: UIImageView        = cell.viewWithTag(Resource.SpeciesCategoryLabelTag) as! UIImageView

    padLock.image = UIImage(named: "PadlockIcon")
    padLock.alpha = 0.7


    let speciesGroupFreeArray: Array<String>
    let speciesGroupVertebratesArray: Array<String>
    let speciesGroupInvertebratesArray: Array<String>

    speciesGroupFreeArray = ["eels", "Mammals", "Annelids", "Bivalvians", "Cephalopods", "Cool oddities", "Crustacean", "Echinoderms", "Hydrozoans", "Isopods"]
    speciesGroupVertebratesArray = ["Fish", "Sharks", "Rays", "Reptilia", "Syngnathiformes"]
    speciesGroupInvertebratesArray = ["Corals", "Gastropods"]

    let fishesPurchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool (forKey: "ReefLife5Fishes")
    let sharksPurchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool (forKey: "ReefLife6Sharks")
    let nudisPurchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool (forKey: "ReefLife7Nudis")
    let turtlesPurchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool (forKey: "ReefLife8Turtles")
    let seahorsesPurchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool (forKey: "ReefLife9Seahorses")
    let coralsPurchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool (forKey: "ReefLife4Corals")
    let vertebratesPurchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool (forKey: "ReefLife3Vertebrates")
    let invertebratesPurchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool (forKey: "ReefLife2Invertebrates")
    let fullPurchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool (forKey: "ReefLife1Full")


    let categoryName = self.species[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].group

    if fullPurchased == true {

        padLock.isHidden = true

    } else if speciesGroupVertebratesArray.contains(categoryName) {

        if vertebratesPurchased == true {

            padLock.isHidden = true

        } else {

            if categoryName == "Fish" {
                if fishesPurchased == true{
                    padLock.isHidden = true
                } else{

                }
            } else if (categoryName == "Sharks" || categoryName == "Rays" ) {
                if sharksPurchased == true{
                    padLock.isHidden = true
                } else{

                }
            } else if categoryName == "Syngnathiformes" {
                if seahorsesPurchased == true{
                    padLock.isHidden = true
                } else{

                }
            } else if categoryName == "Reptilia" {
                if turtlesPurchased == true{
                    padLock.isHidden = true
                } else{

                }
            }
        }

    } else if speciesGroupInvertebratesArray.contains(categoryName) {

        if invertebratesPurchased == true {
            padLock.isHidden = true

        } else {

            if categoryName == "Corals" {
                if coralsPurchased == true{
                    padLock.isHidden = true
                } else{

                }
            } else if categoryName == "Gastropods" {
                if nudisPurchased == true{
                    padLock.isHidden = true
                } else{

                }
            }
        }
    }

    if speciesGroupFreeArray.contains(categoryName) {

        padLock.isHidden = true
    }





    // ****  Adding Padlock Ends HERE  ****


    //
    //  We now need to set our photo. First, we need to fetch the photo based on our specie
    //  id.
    //
    let photos = AppDelegate.getRLDatabase().getSpeciePhotos(self.species[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].id)

    //
    //  Set the image for our UIImageView.
    //
    if photos.isEmpty != true
    {
        specieImage.clipsToBounds = true
        specieImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        specieImage.image = UIImage(named: photos[0].name)


        //            specieImage.image = UIImage(named: photos[0].name)?.resizeTo(specieImage.bounds)
    }
    else
    {
        specieImage.image = UIImage(named: Resource.UnknownImage)?.resizeTo(specieImage.bounds)
    }

    //
    //  Return our new cell.
    //
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You should consider using a `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only ever sets `padlock.isHidden = true`. If you get a recycled cell where the padlock is already hidden, there's nothing to unhide it.

You need to explicitly set the padlock `isHidden` state in all cases.

Given your somewhat contorted code for setting the isHidden property, the simplest way to fix your current code would be to set `padlock.isHidden = false` At the beginning of your `cellForRowAt()` method. Then, if none of the cases set isHidden to true, it will always be unbidden, even in a case where you are reconfiguring a recycled cell where the padlock was hidden.

#### EDIT:

This a key take-away for managing table views and collection views in iOS. Always assume that a cell comes to you with all views set to a non-default state. Your code always needs to explicitly set every view to a specific state.

Think of a table view cell as a paper patient info form at a doctor's office where the office recycles the forms, and doesn't erase the info left by the previous patient. You always have to erase the info left by the previous patient. If you don't have an allergy to peanuts, it's not enough to simply **not check** that box. You have to erase the previous check marks and other info, or the previous patient's info will get mixed up with yours.

That's what's happening with your padlock.isHidden state. You're assuming it starts out in the default state, but it may not.

Answer (score 2):

Please try replace this

```
if speciesGroupFreeArray.contains(categoryName) {
    padLock.isHidden = true
}
```

to

```
padLock.isHidden = speciesGroupFreeArray.contains(categoryName)
```

Comment: Not sure I follow how that would help the refresh issue?  The padlock image is displayed correctly the first time, just randomly changes from item to item when i scroll

Comment: @DavidSanford try it and see.